# XLSXWriter Pandas Export Truncates or Rounds Numbers

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm having trouble exporting a dataframe with xlsxwriter. A column with very long database key integers is truncated and shows in scientific notation.  How do I setup pandas and xlsxwriter to pass the entire number through the dataframe to the xlsxwriter instead of giving me a truncated result?

The column that I'm having trouble with is newdf['Record ID'], so please help me adjust the code below so that that the entire number passes through.

I tried converting this to a string, but it still shows up in excel as a truncated number in scientific notation.  I think the scientific notation is fine, but I cannot afford the truncation.

```
    output = io.BytesIO()
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
    newdf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='NewDF Sheet')
    writer.save()
    resp = make_response(output.getvalue())
    resp.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=output.xlsx"
    resp.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
```

The code above is running in a flask application and exports the dataframe to an xlsx file.  The dataframe contains columns newdf['Record ID'] that should be exporting the entire number, but it only exports the first several digits and the ends show up as zero.  This also shows up in scientific notation.

UPDATE:  I solved my issue by setting the option in excel writer as options={'strings_to_numbers': False} as shown below.  The column was actually already a string in pandas, but still is written by excelwriter as a number unless you set this option. I'm including the string conversion in my answer for a complete solution.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter', options={'strings_to_numbers': False})
newdf['Record ID'] = newdf['Record ID'].astype('str')
newdf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='NewDF Sheet', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: How many digits are the integers? Excel uses IEEE-754 double floats for all integer and floating point data. That has a general precision of 15 digits. To write longer integers you will have to write them as strings by converting them to strings in the data frame.

Comment: So this pointed me in the right direction, but I had to set the string_to_numbers setting to get it to work.  I only needed the data as text.  If someone needed numbers, could they then just run cell formatting on that column to get it to convert to number after it has been written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by setting the option in excel writer as options={'strings_to_numbers': False} as shown below. The column was actually already a string in pandas, but still is written by excelwriter as a number unless you set this option. I'm including the string conversion in my answer for a complete solution.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter', options={'strings_to_numbers': False})
newdf['Record ID'] = newdf['Record ID'].astype('str')
newdf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='NewDF Sheet', index=False)
writer.save()
```